# How can I make xcode 8 warn on nullable block pointers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nullpointerexception, nullable

Testing the recent nullable/nonnull annotations I wrote the simple basic method:

```
- (void)testAnalyzer:(nullable void (^)(BOOL success))completion
{
    // Do stuff
    completion(YES);
}
```

I was expecting the compiler to reject this code, or at least flag it for me to require a conditional around the `completion()` call, but xcode doesn't mind. On the other hand, if I set the parameter to `nonnull` then xcode won't compile code which passes nil to the method.

Looking through xcode build settings I see one named "Misuse of 'nonnull'", so there is no equivalent for "Misuse of 'nullable'"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  At least, I couldn't see a way that you can.

Captured in rdar://30309846.

Thanks for asking-- the compiler really should catch this.